# How to display transparent images PyQt QWidget

Tags: python, image, opencv, pyqt

I'm using OpenCV for some image processing and want to create a transparent overlay on my screen using PyQt widgets. Below I have a basic example of sending a basic frame from opencv to PyQt through a signal/slot and displaying it on the window. The issue is I can't get the transparent background using this method, instead it is just a black background:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread
import numpy as np
import os


class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def run(self):
        img = np.zeros((500, 500, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (200, 200), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        while True
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(img)
        


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Qt live label demo")
        self.disply_width = 1920
        self.display_height = 1080
        # create the label that holds the image
        self.image_label = QLabel(self)
        self.image_label.resize(self.disply_width, self.display_height)
        # create a text label
        self.textLabel = QLabel('Webcam')
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")

        # create a vertical box layout and add the two labels
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.image_label)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textLabel)
        # set the vbox layout as the widgets layout
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        # create the video capture thread
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        # connect its signal to the update_image slot
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        # start the thread
        self.thread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(qt_img)

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(
            rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(
            self.disply_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = App()
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If it isn't possible to send a frame with an alpha channel to PyQt, I was wondering if it's possible to just send the rectangle 4 point location and use the PyQt paint to draw a rectangle on screen? I think this would require a widget.update() but I'm not sure where to invoke that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use transparencies then the colors and the image must be 4-channel, in your case you are passing a 3-channel color to the cv2.rectangle method and then converting you use a 3-channel format in QImage. On the other hand cv2.rectangle returns the drawn image, it does not modify the input array.

```py
def run(self):
    img = np.zeros((500, 500, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    output = cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (200, 200), (0, 0, 255, 255), 2)
    while True:
        self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(output)
        QThread.msleep(1)
```

```
def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
    h, w, ch = cv_img.shape
    bytes_per_line = ch * w
    convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(
        cv_img.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGBA8888
    )
    p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(
        self.disply_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio
    )
    return QPixmap.fromImage(p)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. How would I align the image label to the middle of the screen (vertically). From opencv I'm sending a 2560x720 image and it scales it to the window screen of 1920x1080, but then the image appears in the top of the screen. Do I change anything before doing the video scaling in Qt? I tried ` self.image_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)` in the update_image function but that doesn't seem to work